# Assigning a namespace to a namespace variable

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm curious if it's possible to do something like this:

```
namespace GameXYNamespace
{
    int value3 = 5;
}

namespace Game;

switch (value)
{
case value2:
    Game = GameXYNamespace;
    break;
}

Game.value3++;
```

I'm just wondering, because i have multiple namespaces which are almost the same and I initialize them the exact same way. So instead of doing it like 7x in a switch statement, I thought i could somehow assign a namespace to a variable in a switch statement and do the value assigning part only once at the bottom, by accessing the namespace members through the assigned namespace variable. If it's not possible is there a different way of avoiding redundant code like this:

```
GameX::Level = DownloadLevel();
GameY::Level = DownloadLevel();
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't do that but you could with objects. Why don't you use objects for this purpose?

Comment: @Jack I use namespaces, because i have multiple .cpp and .h files per game and i dont like naming my functions like GameX_Initialize(), so i decided to go with namespaces so i can order everything and use the same function names multiple times.

Comment: Indeed I wasn't talking about `GameX_Initialize` but about class `Game { ... }` `class GameX : public Game { }`. Namespaces are just a way to partition symbols, they don't offer you any object oriented advantage.

Comment: You seem to have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you have multiple "almost the same" namespaces? Are you trying to use namespaces for something that they weren't designed for?

Comment: The simple answer is "No".